# How to use relay connection in GraphQL Schema for mutation

Tags: javascript, graphql, relayjs, relay, graphql-js

I am trying to use graphql-relay connectionDefinitions in GraphQL schema so as to add Edges & Nodes in my mutation calls.

My project context: I have custom field object that I need to update and show with below mutation call

```
    const CustomFieldDefinition = new GraphQLInputObjectType({
                name: 'CustomFieldDefinitions',
                fields: {
                    schem: {
                        type: GraphQLString
                    },
                    deleted: {
                        type: GraphQLBoolean
                    },
                    associatedEntityTypes: {
                        type: GraphQLString
                    },
                    name: {
                        type: GraphQLString
                    },
                    id: {
                        type: GraphQLID
                    }
                }
            })

    const { connectionType: Common_CustomFieldDefinitionConnection } =
            connectionDefinitions({
                   name: 'Common_CustomFieldDefinitionEdge',
                   nodeType: CustomFieldDefinition
        });

    const createCommon_CustomFieldDefinition = mutationWithClientMutationId({
        name: 'CreateCommon_CustomFieldDefinition',
        inputFields: {
            customFieldDefinition: {type: Common_CustomFieldDefinitionConnection},
            clientMutationId: {type: GraphQLString}
        },
        outputFields: {
            customFieldDefinition: {
                type: CustomFieldDefinition,
                resolve: (obj) => {
                    return (obj.customFieldDefinitions[obj.customFieldDefinitions.length-1])
                }
            }
        },
        mutateAndGetPayload: (params) => {
            return Promise.resolve(
                updateCustomField(params)   // Think of it as a method which update all custom fields.
            );
        }
    });

    const Mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
            name: 'Mutation',
            fields: {
                createCommon_CustomFieldDefinition: createCommon_CustomFieldDefinition
            }
        });

    const mySchema = new GraphQLSchema({
        mutation: Mutation
    });

    module.exports = mySchema;
```

This is the Mutation call that I am trying to make work

```
mutation {
  createCommon_CustomFieldDefinition(input:{
    clientMutationId: "1442",
    commonCustomFieldDefinition: {
         name: "Vamsi_date",
         schem: "Anything",
         associatedEntityTypes :"CUSTOMER"
    }
 }) {
    clientMutationId
    commonCustomFieldDefinitionEdge{
      node{
        name
        id
        schem
       }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem that I am facing here is that whenever I start my server I get error as

```
Error: CustomFieldDefinition.customFieldDefinitions field type must be Input Type but got: Common_CustomFieldDefinitionEdgeConnection.
```

How can I resolve this? I think I am doing something wrong in below code.

```
const { connectionType: Common_CustomFieldDefinitionConnection } =
            connectionDefinitions({
                   name: 'Common_CustomFieldDefinitionEdge',
                   nodeType: CustomFieldDefinition
        });
```

Comment: i guess inputFields can't be of customtype

Comment: No it can have customType, that I have tried in past as well

Comment: i guess yes in graphql,but i guess no in graphql-relay, and connections on input fields `edges`, `node`. really??

Comment: @p0k8_ I just edited the mutation call in above qn. So as per mutation call I expect commonCustomFieldDefinitionEdge with node, Is not we need Relay connection for that?

Comment: ok just imagine, how would your `inputfields`= `params` look in `mutateAndGetPayload: (params)`, just put the expected object in `params`

Comment: Sorry @p0k8_ I didn't get you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136811/discussion-between-p0k8-and-ranjeet-gautam).

Comment: inputfield accept GraphQLInputObjectType only, you have provided GraphQLobjectType